# Split unicode word in php with regex match or any other way

Tags: php, regex

Need to search n split specific part from unicode string for example if word is لاحاصل need to search لا out of it in shape of matches as حاصل and لا any help ?

Comment: Can you post the PHP that you have tried so far?

Comment: mb_split("/$entry/",$word); i am using this here $entry is لا coming from database and $word is لاحاصل coming from user input..... i have checked database is sending correct word.

Comment: Can you post the _whole_ PHP file you are using to attempt this?

Comment: Its whole part of big thing n data is coming from different streams but here is my function view
private static function core($combinations, $word)
        {
            $results = array();
            
            foreach($combinations as $single)
            {
                $entry = $single['word'];
                $outs = mb_split("/$entry/",$word);
                if(count($outs)>0)
                {$entry = array();
                    $entry['combination'] = $single['word'];
                    $entry['leftover'] = $outs[1];
                    $results[] = $entry;}}return $results; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with the `u` modifier to have multi-byte support. Then you can use the fourth argument to specify you want both the delimiter and delimited parts:

```
$word = "لاحاصل";
$entry = "لا";
$arr = preg_split("/($entry)/u", $word, null,
                  PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE + PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 
echo $arr[0] . "<br>"; // لا
echo $arr[1] . "<br>"; // حاصل
```

Don't forget the brackets around *$entry* to make it a capture group. This way it works with `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`.